# Duplicate logs in Kibana after fingerprints

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-plugin

I have been getting duplicate logs for every API hit in Kibana, so I added the fingerprint plugin to provide unique ids for the same. Following is the segment I added in my logstash configuration..

logstash.conf

```
... filter {
  fingerprint {
    source => "message"
    target => "[@metadata][fingerprint]"
    method => "MURMUR3"
  }
} ...
```

I used the fingerprint as my document Id, and after this I do not get duplicates in the new hits.
I.E now onwards I get one log for every API hit, but the old logs remain the same(they still have duplicates).

Is there any way that I can remove duplicates from my old logs too?

Comment: Is the data too large for manually deleting the duplicates using the Delete API?

Comment: How exactly do I manually delete? Like I couldn't find where the logs are stored(new to ELK). Can you mention any reference or something?